# How to notify the user when exo player is buffering the video in Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

There is one interface in `ExoPlayer` class called `EventListener`. But there isn't any method that notifies whether it's being buffered or not.

Are there any other callback functions for checking the state of the `ExoPlayer`?

Answer (score 2):

```
    private lateinit var player: SimpleExoPlayer
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this)
 
    player.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
        override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
          
            if (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                videoProgress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                videoProgress.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
```

You can use the Player.STABUFFERING to notify the user if the video is buffering with the help of a progress bar and hide it when the state is changed.

Answer (score 1):

> But there isn't any method that notifies whether it's being buffered or not.

Do you mean ***to see when we have had sufficient buffer***?

As I know, for EXOplayer:

```
...
} else if (state == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
  boolean isNewlyReady = enabledRenderers.length > 0
      ? (allRenderersReadyOrEnded && haveSufficientBuffer(rebuffering))
      : isTimelineReady(playingPeriodDurationUs);
  if (isNewlyReady) {
    setState(ExoPlayer.STATE_READY);
    if (playWhenReady) {
      startRenderers();
    }
  }
} else if (state == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
  boolean isStillReady = enabledRenderers.length > 0 ? allRenderersReadyOrEnded
      : isTimelineReady(playingPeriodDurationUs);
  if (!isStillReady) {
    rebuffering = playWhenReady;
    setState(ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING);
    stopRenderers();
  }
}
```

...

whew setState:

```
private void setState(int state) {
  if (this.state != state) {
    this.state = state;
    eventHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_STATE_CHANGED, state, 0).sendToTarget();
  }
}
```

Then:

```
void handleEvent(Message msg) {
  switch (msg.what) {
    case ExoPlayerImplInternal.MSG_STATE_CHANGED: {
      playbackState = msg.arg1;
      for (EventListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady, playbackState);
      }
      break;
    }
    ...
```

Seems that we can get playbackState by this way?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late to answer but if someone is still looking for an answer, then ExoPlayer already provides callbacks to identify the player's playback states.
The EventListener interface provides a method called `onPlaybackStateChanged()` which gives updates about the player's state.
The [EventLogger](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/util/EventLogger.java#L103) already implements this and in the logcat, you may find below logs while playing a stream.

```
D EventLogger: state [0.00, true, I]
D EventLogger: state [0.01, true, B]
D EventLogger: state [3.09, true, R]
```

Where I is for STATE_IDLE, B is for STATE_BUFFERING, and R is for STATE_READY.
You may want to implement the Player.EventListener to get notified when the player is buffering.
There is one more state called STATE_ENDED which gets logged when the player has stopped playing the stream.

I believe this [link](https://exoplayer.dev/listening-to-player-events.html#playback-state) will give you even more information.